# Debugging c++ built with a makefile in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, visual-studio-code

I have an existing code base that builds with a makefile and I'd like to use Visual Studio Code to run it.

I started by opening my project directory with Visual Studio Code.
Then, for building I created a task as per http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp :

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "bash",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args":["-c", "cd build && make"]
}
```

which works fine. I then downloaded the C++ extension and created a launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "C++ Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "targetArchitecture": "x64",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/myProgram",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "linux": {
            "MIMode": "gdb"
        },
        "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        },
        "windows": {
            "MIMode": "gdb"
        }
    },
    // attach here, which I don't care about
]
}
```

This launch file allows me to start my program using the built-in debugger. I know that it works because I see all the symbol files getting loaded and I can pause the program.

However, VS Code doesn't "see" my source files; when I pause it says

```
 Source /Unknown Source is not available.
```

I also can't set breakpoints in the source. I see that *some* symbols get loaded though as I can see my function names on the call stack when I pause execution.

So what did I miss? Do I absolutely have to do as they say here ( http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp ) and make a g++ task where I'll have to manually input all my include paths and linker inputs? The point of using a makefile in the first place was to not have to do this tedious stuff...

Thanks a lot to anyone who knows how to wrangle VS code.

Comment: I think we need to see the makefile to know what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to debug by just using `tasks.json` and `launch.json`.

Are you sure you have the `-g` option set in your makefile?

Another thing - you can have your task be executed on launch by adding
`"preLaunchTask": "bash"` to your your `launch.json`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

At windows; `Mingw`, `gdb` and `-g` parameter at compilation of the executable are necessary with c/c++ extension. `"preLaunchTask": "bash"` is not necessary in `launch.json`.